# how do I fix exception on calling length on an empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular service which on startup contains an empty array.  In the getter, I log what it is returning.  I would like avoid having to write logic around a logging statement, and I would like the logging statement to stay, for now.

here's the provider:

```
appInstance.service('ActivityNavigationDataService',
    ['$log', '$rootScope', 'UIManager',
    function($log, $rootScope, UIManager) {
        $log.debug('ActivityNavigationDataService constructor');

        $rootScope.activities = [];

        UIManager.registerActivityListener($rootScope, activitiesUpdated);

        function activitiesUpdated(event, activities) {
            $rootScope.activities = activities;
        }

        this.getActivities = function() {
            $log.debug('returning ' + $rootScope.activities.length + ' activities');
            return $rootScope.activities;
        };
}]);
```

here's the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Object.getActivities (ActivityNavigationDataService.js:28)
>       at new ActivityNavigationServiceController (ActivityNavigationServiceController.js:31)
>       at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5055)
>       at $controller (angular.js:11015)
>       at UIManager.js:40
>       at processQueue (angular.js:17051)
>       at angular.js:17095
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18233)
>       at angular.js:18462
>       at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6362) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

thoughts?
Thnx, Matt

**edit**:
I think the problem is the ActivityNavigationDataService is not finished loaded and constructed by the time activitiesUpdated is called.

I am loading the service via define[] like this:

```
define(['services/ActivityNavigationDataService',
        // theres others here
        'controllers/UIManager'],
    function() {
        'use strict';
        var appInstance = angular.module('obdPortletApp');
        appInstance.controller('obdMasterController', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$log', 'UIManager', 
                function($rootScope, $scope, $log, UIManager) {

                UIManager.initialize();
                UIManager.buildUI();
        }]);
    }
);
```

The UIManager.buildUI() method uses ocLazyLoad to load additional resources, which in turn push activities to the ActivityNavigationService through a broadcasted message, not direct reference to the service.

So I think something is off on timing.

Comment: The array is not empty if you have this exception. It means that `$rootScope` **is** undefined. It is as if you are doing `undefined.length`. `[].length` works fine even though it is empty

Comment: Well that or the `activitiesUpdated` event listener has set `$rootScope.activities` to `undefined`.

Comment: I was getting the same error (from similar log method) in activitiesUpdated. I'm inclined to believe $rootscope is undefined.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Your `activitiesUpdated()` handler is getting `undefined` for `activities`.  If you are the one returning the `activities` make sure you return an empty array.  However, if you don't, you could do something like this:

```
function activitiesUpdated(event, activities) {
  $rootScope.activities = activities || [];
}
```